# how to tell the agent move to right place in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm now doing some RL-relative work but something bothered me.
Now I have a 64x64 blank img and nine 8x2 rectangles on it. The position of rectangles are all random initial. I want to make this 9 rectangles be regular putted(eg 3 rows and 3 cols 3x3, or 441 and so on).Each rect has 5 action(go left/up/right/down or stay still), The total action space is 9*5. The observation is each rect's bbox, so total length is 9*4.
I use stable-baseline3 and choose PPO algorithm, the reward is

1. each rect must in 64x64
2. each rect must not be overlapped
3. each rect's distance with other rect must bigger than 4

But when I train this, only one rect moved, the actor never choose other rect, I dont know where wrong, could anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!!